# Subclass generics in hash maps?

Tags: java, generics, collections, arraylist

```
 public class people {

}

class friend extends people {

}

class coworkers extends people {

}

class family extends people {

}

public void fillMaps(){
    ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<family>> familyNames = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<family>>();
    ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<coworkers>> coworkersNames = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<coworkers>>();
    ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<friend>> friendNames = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<friend>>();
    populateMap(family.class, familyNames);
    populateMap(coworkers.class, coworkersNames);
    populateMap(friend.class, friendNames);
}

private <T> void populateMap(Class<T> clazz, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<people>> map) {
        if (clazz == family.class) {
            map.put("example", new ArrayList<family>());
        }
        if (clazz == coworkers.class) {
            map.put("example", new ArrayList<coworkers>());
        }
        if (clazz == friend.class) {
            map.put("example", new ArrayList<friend>());
        }

}
```

family, coworkers, and friend classes all extend from the superclass called people.  Why doesn't the method below allow me to use the class as an argument to the parameters of the populateMap method.  Also, why doesn't it allow me to pass a subclass collection as an argument here?

```
error:
The method populateMap(Class<T>, ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<people>>) is not applicable for the arguments (Class<family>, ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<family>>)
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList<family>` isn't considered as a subtype of `Collection<people>`
`ArrayList<family>` subtype of `Collection<family>` 
`ArrayList<people>` subtype of `Collection<people>`

you want to have this

```
private <T extends people> void populateMap(ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<T>> map) {

                map.put("example", new ArrayList<T>());


    }
```

Comment: it got rid of the errors inside of fillMaps().  but now I see errors with the map.put sections.  it says:
'code'The method put(String, Collection<T>) in the type Map<String,Collection<T>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<family>)'code'

Comment: There's no need to pass the class parameter.

Comment: `private <T extends people> void populateMap` to be precise :)

Comment: why do we not need to pass the class parameter?

Comment: @StephenD: because the type parameter of the passed map already contains the type info needed to instantiate the proper ArrayList.

Comment: in generics the Type of T will be decided depending on the value of T passed as parameter

Answer (score 3):

Because, `ArrayList<family>` isn't considered as a subtype of `Collection<people>` and hence cannot be assigned. The concept of `Polymorphism` doesn't extend to Java generics the same way as they do to classes.

```
private <T> void populateMap(ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<T>> map) {
    map.put("example", new ArrayList<T>());
}
```

Comment: is there a way around this?

Comment: Why not? `ArrayList` implements `Collection`. Also if this was so, `map.put` would also fail.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes ArrayList does but ArrayList<family> cannot be assigned to Collection<people>. ArrayList<people> on the other hand can be. They are considered different by the compiler to protect the collection because the type isn't available at runtime (due to type erasure).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
private <T> void populateMap(Class<T> clazz, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<? extends people>> map) {
...
}
```

`Collection<family>` should be valid for `Collection<? extends people>` as `family` extends `people`.  But it is probably not what you want, Rahul's answer is what you probably want.

Comment: No, this also fails to compile.