# Insert a hashmap into a hashmap?

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap

```
public class People {
    class Family extends People {
    }
}

public class Together {
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<Family>> familyMap= new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Collection<Family>>();
    private static ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>>> registry2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>>>();

    static {
        registry2.put(Family.class.toString(), familyMap); 
    }
}
```

(I already tried changing the declaration of `registry2` to having `? extends People`

The error is:
`The method put(String, ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<People>>) in the type Map<String,ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<People>>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, ConcurrentMap<String,Collection<Family>>)`

How can I put `familyMap` into the `registry2` hashmap?

Comment: a `Collection<Family>` is not a `Collection<People>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: I have tried that, it doesn't like that either.  I understand that the heirarchy of polymorphism isn't the same with generics.  Is there another way of putting familyMap into registry2?

Comment: Please, read the answers to your questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17196851/1237040) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17200675/1237040). Why are you making the same mistakes again and again? "Java Generics are NOT covariant!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Map problem : this is rather a Generics problem. You assume that a `Collection<Family>` is a subclass of `Collection<People>` because `Family extends People`, but this is not the case.

They are in fact totally different types, so the compiler complains that you are not passing arguments of the right type.

---

You can resolve the issue by making familyMap a Map that holds a collection of People objects. Your code will just happen to be putting Family objects into it, which is fine, because a Family IS a People.

But when getting the Family objects back out of the map you'll need to typecast them to a Family if you need to use specific Family functions, though there is some risk that down the road a People (and not a Family) object could sneak into it. You may want to consider a different design paradigm to mitigate that risk.

Comment: So if they don't extend similarily to how classes extend, is there no way of doing this?

Comment: @StephenD You may 1)replace `Collection<Family>>` and `Collection<People>>` with `Family[]` and `People[]` because `Family[]` extends `People[]` or 2) replace `ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<Family>> familyMap` with `ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>> familyMap`.

Comment: There is if you can change some of the types somewhere.  For instance, you could use `ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<? extends People>>`.

Comment: Yes, it's the best solution by far

Comment: If I put a `family` object casted as a `people` object, will I lose the distinct values of whatever the `family` object had within it's variables when I take it out of the `people` map and cast it back as a `family` object?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put an incompatible type in because `familyMap` is a `Collection<Family>` and not a `Collection<People>` which you specify in `registry2` (`ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<People>>`)

Comment: Well, can I still put the hashmap into the hashmap?

Comment: Yes, just change it to `Family` or `People`, whichever you intended.